# Кэширование страницы в WebView

Tags: android, webview, кэширование

Как известно при повороте экрана, `Activity` и `WebView` пересоздаётся, и заново загружается первая страница. Так как это отнимает время, я решил кешировать страницу, чтобы при повороте экрана, он уже загружал исходную страницу с кэша. Читал немало зарубежных статей, и почти всегда по-разному происходить реализация, так как у меня с переводом проблемы, мне немного сложно с них брать информацию. Помогите, как можно реализовать кэширование в `WebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы видел 2 способа реализации вашего вопроса:

1. **Традиционный:** в рамках стандартного кэша `WebView`. Механизм реализации кэша многократно описан и известен. Небольшое уточнение будет только касаться загрузки HTML из кэша. Тут к сожалению прямого доступа к файлам в кэше нет (вроде бы), есть только способ управления загрузкой из кэша. В принципе можно попробовать детектировать поворот экрана и после поворота экрана при загрузке страницы применить нечтно вроде: `webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)` - это попытка загрузить сначала кэш и только потом загружать из сети
2. **Самопальный:** надо прочитать страницу в виде HTML кода. Например, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479833/is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-code-from-webview). Далее при повороте экрана "запихнуть" полученный `String` HTML'а в `Bundle` `savedStateInstance` и соответственно вытащить HTML его в `Activity.onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstance)` и заслать в `WebView`

ИМХО, мне кажется второй способ будет самый кучерявый.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например:  [это](http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html) и [это](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/)

Кроме того, вебвью автоматом кеширует страницу(судя по постам на stackoverflow)

Comment: Да читал я это,но я так и не понял как забирать из кэша Html файл.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за советы нашел решение,использовал *android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden*
данный код отменяет перезапуск приложения при заданных случаях,думаю стандартные браузеры так же это реализовали.Я неправильно формулировал проблему,мне нужно было просто сохранить состояние при повороте,просто не знал как,и решил кэшировать.Возьму на заметку ваши решения.